# How to use ZipPackage to create a zip

Tags: c#, zip

I've seen the document on MSDN about the [ZipPackage class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.zippackage.aspx).

The example there is not very useful, can anyone provide an example about this class?

Answer (score 5):

Here an example, note that:
 - ZipPackage seem to do not compress
 - The generated zip has an undesired file "[Content_Types].xml"
 - [System.IO.Compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) since .Net 4.5 seems to be a good alternative

You have, in Visual Studio, to add reference to "WindowsBase" (without prefix like "System.IO.")

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Packaging;
using System.IO;

namespace TestZip
{
 public static class  Program
 {
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Join("\n", new string[1000].Select(s => "Something to zip.").ToArray()));
   byte[] zippedBytes;
   using(MemoryStream zipStream = new MemoryStream())
   {
    using (Package package = Package.Open(zipStream, FileMode.Create))
    {
     PackagePart document = package.CreatePart(new Uri("/test.txt", UriKind.Relative), "");
     using (MemoryStream dataStream = new MemoryStream(data))
     {
      document.GetStream().WriteAll(dataStream);
     }     
    }    
    zippedBytes = zipStream.ToArray();
   }
   File.WriteAllBytes("test.zip", zippedBytes);
  }

  private static void WriteAll(this Stream target, Stream source)
  {
   const int bufSize = 0x1000;
   byte[] buf = new byte[bufSize];
   int bytesRead = 0;
   while ((bytesRead = source.Read(buf, 0, bufSize)) > 0)
    target.Write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this code project -

[C# Use Zip Archives without External Libraries](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/209731/Csharp-use-Zip-archives-without-external-libraries).