# C# - Compress byte[]

Tags: c#, .net

I receive a zip file base64 string, convert to byte[], open in memory, modify content, and then 'compress' the new byte[] to base64 string again.

My problem, I don't know how to 'compress' the new byte[] to zip format.

```
public string ModifyZipContent(string base64) {
    ZipPackage zipPackage = null;
    MemoryStream memoryStream = null;

    long lenght;

    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    byte[] buffer;
    byte[] newData;

    int arrayOffset = 0;

    memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    memoryStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

    zipPackage = (ZipPackage)Package.Open(memoryStream, FileMode.Open);

    PackagePartCollection zipParts = zipPackage.GetParts();

    // this is awful
        foreach(ZipPackagePart zipPart in zipParts) {
            using(Stream stream = zipPart.GetStream()) {
                arrayOffset += (int)stream.Length;
            }
        }

        newData = new byte[arrayOffset];
    // end

    arrayOffset = 0;
    foreach(ZipPackagePart zipPart in zipParts) {
        using(Stream stream = zipPart.GetStream()) {
            lenght = stream.Length;
            buffer = new byte[lenght];

            stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)lenght);

            Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, newData, arrayOffset, buffer.Length);
            arrayOffset += buffer.Length;
        }
    }

    return Convert.ToBase64String(newData);
}
```

Comment: PS: In this particular case, I don't make any changes to data because I want to know if the new base64 string is equal to the old, so, if it's true, I can make changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use ZipPackage to create a zip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888805/how-to-use-zippackage-to-create-a-zip)

Comment: FYI converting a `byte[]` to base64 does not "compress" it - it actually results in a 33% _bigger_ array.  It takes raw binary data and encodes in a subset of ASCII characters.

Comment: It seems like File.WriteAllBytes do all the work, but I can't use that because I don't have access to disk, I need to do 'on the fly' in memory and return the modified zip.

I'm trying to explain myself, sorry if I can't

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully tested this, but something along these lines should work...

```
// Requires System.IO.Compression using statement.

byte[] bytes = new byte[256]; // Your byte[] would be here instead of this empty one.
using (var zipFile = ZipFile.Open("C:/ZipFile.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Update))
{
    var entry = zipFile.CreateEntry("YourEntryPathHere");
    using (var stream = entry.Open())
    {
        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
}
```